# Docker nginx container: http code 400

Tags: macos, docker, nginx, networking, docker-for-mac

I’m a new in docker and I’m trying to run nginx from https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

1. I pulled the image

`docker pull nginx`

2. I’m running container

`docker run --rm --name=some-nginx -p 8080:80 nginx`

but getting http 400 all time when I open localhost:8080 in browser in local machine. Log from docker output:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2017:23:07:11 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xB5\x01\x00\x00\xB1\x03\x03\x81e|u\x93\xFC`Qo\xC8\xE6y\x18{%\x83\x8C\xC2a\xC93V\xB5;\xC0V\xDC\x10{\xC9)X\x00\x00\x1E\xC0+\xC0/\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0,\xC00\xC0" 400 173 "-" "-" "-"
```

What’s wrong? I checked nginx inside the containter (`curl localhost`) and it works.

Thank you.

Comment: It does not look like a Nginx or proxy problem. Error 4xx means that the client is not sending the correct data to server to process. If you send your code request and server handling, I think we could help you way more.

Comment: I don't know. It's a just static status page from nginx. I don't need data for sending, just get request for localhost:8080

Comment: The status page sholud just tell you about error (when you think about web proxy). The error 4xx tells you that the data from web is passing throught Nginx and some of that is arriving in your server handler. This means your service (localhost:8080) does not know how to interpret this data. I think you should provide a more detailed description of the case.

Comment: Fabiano, thank you for helping. I'm just following the guide https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/ New nginx installation without custom config. I want to see just service page from nginx and understand how it works thogether (I mean docker with nginx container -> local machine).

Comment: You may what to open `http://localhost:8080` instead of just `localhost:8080`. Browsers may assume `https` if you don't specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it now. It's a bit complicated, but I will try to simplify:

You  are binding the 8080 host port to 80 container port. So, if you do a `curl localhost` at the host, it means you are not calling Nginx service inside the container, but the port 80 process in your *nix system. Likewise, if you send the same command inside the container, it will work, because it has exposed the default http port (80) inside the container, but not outside. You may confirm this assumption by calling `curl localhost:8080`. If this return as the container command, it is right.

Is it possible to understand?